# Symfony 3: Can't make relations work

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have *Entity(s)* and *EntityHtml(s)* entities which has *one-to-one* relashionship (*Entity* stores metadata and *EntityHtml* acts like a cache, storing ready HTML chunks for rendering).

I have defined a relationship in *Entity class*:

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="EntityHtml")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entityId", referencedColumnName="entityId")
     */
    private $entityHtml;
```

but it isn't working. Also I have a kind of feeling, that annotations don't work at all, because changing them has no effect upon workability of the application.

On the other hand, messing with *.orm.xml(s)* reflects in how application works.

- Can I tell *Symfony* to update ORM XMLs based on changes to annotations?
- Should I duplicate relation *meta* to XML?
- Does *Symfony* use info at both *XML* and *annotations* or does it choose one source?

**config.yml is default one:**

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
```

Comment: You need to update your schema (`php bin/console doctrine:schema:update` I believe) everytime you update the annotations. Did you do that?

Comment: @PietervandenHam I did, but it didn't change XML or db a bit.

Comment: Can you show us your `config.yml`? (The relevant parts)

Comment: @PietervandenHam Done.

Answer (score 0):

Does it make any difference if you try this:

```
/**
  * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="EntityHtml")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity_Id", referencedColumnName="entityId")
  */
```

I'm thinking that "entityId" is the Id in EntityHtml, and you need to specify a different "name" value in JoinColumn. I think I ran into that problem.

Try it - I'm not sure if it will work.

Comment: I believe _name_ here stands for a column name in the referencing table name. I give columns camel-cased names (w/o underscores) in order not to mix multiple namings.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out. It's a configuration issue. In order to make annotations work (xml is default option), you have to explicitly configure it:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    ...

    orm:
        ...
        mappings:
            AppBundle:
                type: annotation
```

Unfortunatelly that's not specified in tutorials.